# sed - output match string with regex

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to extract a substring by regex and output the matched group.

In below example string,the expected output is the string after "package:" and end with ".apk". below code works at beginning part, but the end part not work.

```
echo "package:/data/app/~~6qMr1wvTvXFW_ceh1ptDHA==/com.sample.touch-tOazIbhNj63ME76BG6zrsA==/base.apk=com.sample.touch" |sed -E 's/package:([^ ]+apk)/\1/'
/data/app/~~6qMr1wvTvXFW_ceh1ptDHA==/com.sample.touch-tOazIbhNj63ME76BG6zrsA==/base.apk=com.sample.touch
```

The expected output:

```
/data/app/~~6qMr1wvTvXFW_ceh1ptDHA==/com.sample.touch-tOazIbhNj63ME76BG6zrsA==/base.apk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```sh
sed -E 's/package:([^ ]+apk).*/\1/'
# or
sed 's/package:\([^ ]*apk\).*/\1/'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/zKjFqj):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "package:/data/app/~~6qMr1wvTvXFW_ceh1ptDHA==/com.sample.touch-tOazIbhNj63ME76BG6zrsA==/base.apk=com.sample.touch" | \
sed -E 's/package:([^ ]+apk).*/\1/'
# => /data/app/~~6qMr1wvTvXFW_ceh1ptDHA==/com.sample.touch-tOazIbhNj63ME76BG6zrsA==/base.apk
```

*Details*:

- `-E` - POSIX ERE syntax enabled
- `package:([^ ]+apk).*` - `package:` string, then one or more chars other than a space and then `apk` substring captured into Group 1 (`([^ ]+apk)`), and then the rest of the string (`.*`)
- `\1` - the replacement is Group 1 value.